# What's the best practice for writing an "execute only" Python module?

Tags: python, import, scope, program-entry-point

I have a Python module that is intended exclusively for running as a script and never as something that should be imported, and I'd like to enforce (and communicate) that intention in my code.

What is the best practice for accomplishing this?

---

I can imagine a few options such as wrapping the whole file in

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # All the code in the module
```

or aborting at the start

```
if __name__ != '__main__':
    exit()

# All the code in the module
```

perhaps with a warning

```
if __name__ != '__main__':
    print('You should not import this')
    exit()

# All the code in the module
```

or even an assertion

```
assert __name__ == '__main__', 'You should not import this'
```

But I'm not sure which (if any) is appropriate, stylistically or technically.

Comment: You forgot to escape the `'`. However why do you want to enforce such a thing? If someone really want to import your script wouldn't be difficult to comment a line.

Comment: @Faust: Everything is possible. I'm just trying to make it impossible to do by accident (and clear that that's the intent).

Comment: @Faust: We can debate the scenario elsewhere. Let's not derail the question though: I want to communicate intent (and to the extent possible, "encourage" it).

Comment: I think that the best place for doing it is documentation.

Comment: @Faust: Maybe the scenario is not clear. Someone (probably me or someone who is not a coder) who is not malicious imports the package. If that happens, (1) none of the definitions or code in the package should execute and (2) it would be nice to let the user know what happened. Documentation clearly does not accomplish (1) and is not the best way for that user to accomplish (2).

Comment: Personally I cannot understand why you need (1) and why someone who is not a coder, at some point in his coding-unrelated life, may want to import your program without reading the doc.

Comment: @Faust: In general I've found that it's not helpful to get involved in a question with a use case you "cannot understand". Perhaps this helps focus: What's the best way to prevent all the code in a module from running if it is imported.

Comment: @Faust: Let's get away from the 'why'. After all, why ever use `if __name__ == '__main__':` at all if you're happy with documentation doing the job?

Comment: If you really need to disallow importing your module, I'd definitely raise `ImportError` with a descriptive error message instead of calling `exit()`.

Comment: Well, you asked about what is the more appropriate way to do that. I think that it is not appropriate to do that in any way. `if __name__ == '__main__':` is used to make your `.py` work differently if it is imported or executed directly. It is not intended to forbid the user to do something which is usually legitimate.

Answer (score 3):

While you indeed can do

```
if __name__ != '__main__':
    raise ImportError(...)
    # or maybe just emit a warning
```

it may stand in your feet the other day.

At least, you should keep the functions, classes and other definitions alone - they don't do any harm and maybe you or someone else needs them later.

If you import a module which just exposes functions and classes and values without doing output or other things, all you lose is some milliseconds.

Instead, you should put the code which executes on startup into a function (`main()`?) and execute that in the usual manner.