# Idiom for modules in packages that are not directly executed

Tags: python, import, scope, package, program-entry-point

Is there an idiom or suggested style for modules that are never useful when directly executed, but simply serve as components of a larger package — e.g. those containing definitions, etc.?

For example is it customary to omit `#!/usr/bin/env python`; add a comment; report a message to the user or execute other code (e.g. [using a check](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20923892/656912) of whether or not `__name__` is `'__main__'` — or simply do nothing special?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the python code I write is modules that generally don't get directly called as scripts. Sometimes when I'm working on a small project and don't want to set up a more complex testing system, I'll call my tests for the module bellow `if __name__ == '__main__':`, that way I can quickly test my module just by calling `python modulename.py` (this sometimes does not play nice with relative imports and such but it works well enough for small projects). Whether or not I do this, I drop the shebang and don't give execute remission to the file because I don't like to make modules executable unless they're meant to be run as scripts.